# how to get text from span faster when using python selenium chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler

i want to get text from website and insert them into a list,and found speed of element.text is really slow,i tried get list of span or get its parent and get it then,but nothing changed.Should i get the whole html document and select by using regular expression?
pls tell me how to improve it and why.many thanks for your help.
these are two method i tried:

```
for i in range(0,len(client_deliver_list_html),27):
    if client_deliver_list_html[i+12].text ==0 :continue
    client_cargo = [client_deliver_list_html[i].text,
    client_deliver_list_html[i+1].text,
    client_deliver_list_html[i+3].text,
    client_deliver_list_html[i+5].text,
    int(client_deliver_list_html[i+8]).text,
    client_deliver_list_html[i+9].text,
    float(client_deliver_list_html[i+12].text),
    ]
    cargo_feature = [client_deliver_list_html[i+1],
                     client_deliver_list_html[i+3],
                     client_deliver_list_html[i+5],
                    ]
    if not cargo_feature in feature_list:feature_list.append(cargo_feature)
    client_deliver_list.append(client_cargo)
```

the other one:

```
for tr in client_deliver_list_html:
    client_cargo_atrbt = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name("span")
    if (client_cargo_atrbt[30].text == 0):continue
    client_cargo = [client_cargo_atrbt[1].text,
    client_cargo_atrbt[3].text,
    client_cargo_atrbt[4].text,
    client_cargo_atrbt[6].text,
    int(client_cargo_atrbt[10].text),
    client_cargo_atrbt[11].text,
    float(client_cargo_atrbt[14].text),
    ]
    cargo_feature = [client_cargo[1],
                     client_cargo[2],
                     client_cargo[3],
                    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the span by xpath.

Example:

```
for span in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span"):
    text = span.text
```

Another way to get text:

```
for span in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span"):
    text = span.get_attribute("textContent")
```

You can get get all the span inside of a table with:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[ancestor::table]")
```